# Для чего нужно ключевое слово uniform?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

В документации *Юнити* (конкретно здесь: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html) написано:

> Cg/HLSL can also accept uniform keyword, but it is not necessary:
>
> `uniform float4 _MyColor`;

То есть можно написать ключевое слово `uniform`, но оно не обязательно.

Где-то в книжках/сайтах/форумах написано, что типа если планируется прием данных в переменную из скрипта (с внешнего источника), то надо объявлять переменную именно таким образом (ключевое слово `attribute` сейчас не в счет).

Однако я и без этого ключевого слова спокойно изменял значение из скрипта, например код:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetFloat("_Contrast", contrast);
```

спокойно изменял переменную и без всяких `uniform`.

<strike>Ведь, если звезды зажигают, значит, это кому-нибудь нужно?</strike> Если оно есть, то зачем-то оно нужно? Или всё-таки не нужно и просто разрабы не могут его физически убрать и можно забить теперь навсегда на это? Не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, не знаю по какой причине разработчики *Unity* не уберут это слово из доков, а также возможность не вставлять его в *shaderLab*. Ибо, если верить слухам — компилятор *Unity* приписывает `uniform` автоматически ко всем переменным без модификаторов.

С чем связана такая логика наверное нужно сильно углубиться, чтоб понять. Но в данный момент происходить именно так.